# MUI X Data Grid non-truncated column width

Tags: reactjs, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

MUI X Data Grid truncates a cell data by default if its content overflows the column width. Are there ways to prevent this so that the column width will match the longest text content of the header and the longest content of the cells in that column?

I know you can autosize column width with [MUI X Data Grid Pro](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-dimensions/#autosizing).

But are there ways to do something similar in the non-pro MUI DataGrid? I have tried `renderCell` with a custom JSX cell-component using `textOverflow: ellipsis` and similar but it does not do the trick.

To make it clear, this is what I want to avoid:
[image]

And I want to have this:
[image]